# How to remove array object from for loop

Tags: objective-c

please Help me. I stuck here when deleting an object from array.

```
for (id obj in self.arrSavedImage)
        {
            Class cls = [obj class];

            id newObj = [[cls alloc] init];
            //UIImage *img = nil;
            if([newObj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){

                NSLog(@"class type %@", [newObj class]);
            }
            else{

                [self.arrSavedImage removeObject:obj];
            }

        }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't remove objects from an array you are enumerating over.  Better is to keep a list of the objects you want to delete, and then delete them when you've finished enumerating the original array:

```
NSMutableArray *toDelete = [NSMutableArray new];
for (id obj in self.arrSavedImage)
{
    Class cls = [obj class];
    id newObj = [[cls alloc] init];
    if([newObj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){
        NSLog(@"class type %@", [newObj class]);
    }
    else{
       [toDelete addObject:obj];
    }
}

for (id obj in toDelete)
    [self.arrSavedImage removeObject:obj];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *itemsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id obj in self.arrSavedImage)
    {
        Class cls = [obj class];

        id newObj = [[cls alloc] init];
        //UIImage *img = nil;
        if([newObj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){

            NSLog(@"class type %@", [newObj class]);
        }
        else{

            [itemsToDelete addObject:obj];
        }

    }

[self.arrSavedImage removeObjectsInArray:itemsToDelete];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the object in array while in loop.

You should create a new array with existing array and remove objects from it. Then replace the old array with editedArray.

```
NSMutableArray * editedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.arrSavedImage];

for (id obj in self.arrSavedImage)
        {
            Class cls = [obj class];

            id newObj = [[cls alloc] init];
            //UIImage *img = nil;
            if([newObj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){

                NSLog(@"class type %@", [newObj class]);
            }
            else{

                [editedArray removeObject:obj];
            }

        }

[self.arrSavedImage setArray:editedArray];

editedArray = nil;
```